# Insert multiline example in a table environment

Tags: tables

I would like to put the example in the right cell of a table, and a description on the left. I can't manage to do it though.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\title{Your Paper}

\author{You}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Your abstract.
\end{abstract}

\begin{exe}
\ex \label {basicnolaga}
\gll a b-te c d \\ a.\textsc{nom} v-\textsc{prt} c d \\
\trans `a b c d.'
\end {exe}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{ll}
example above here n three lines & a description
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either explicitly embed the example in a `minipage` placed inside the table or you can use `p{<par-width>}` as a column directive:

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{tabular}{p{3in}l}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \begin{exe}
       \ex \label {basicnolaga}
       \gll a b-te c d                   \\ 
       a.\textsc{nom} v-\textsc{prt} c d \\
       \trans `a b c d.'
    \end {exe}
    example above here n three lines 
    & 
    a description
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```